# How to invest with a low net worth

Tags: stocks, investing, germany

Ok, I have following set up. I am a trainee in Germany. That means I am someone who is going to school part time and works in the company the other time. So my income is low at the moment. Fortunately I saved now 2000€ and I want to invest my money. Since 2000€ is not that much I can't invest it in real estate but I thought that I might invest it in stocks. What are your suggestions on how to make more money of that?

Comment: why is this a bad question ?

Comment: Define invest. Are you fine with losing it all, or are you interested in safety and a 2% return?

Comment: I am fine with losing all

Comment: @IbrahimApachi - Welcome to Money.SE. I did not vote either way, but I'll answer your comment 'why is this a bad question?' The question is too broad, too vague. And one might argue, investing should never have a risk of losing it all. I do that with tiny slivers of my money, and it's called speculating or gambling.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer so to be clear you consider investing in a single individual stock "gambling" and not investing. A perfectly defensible position, but I think it warrants the point that investing in 1 or 2 companies is not really investing but speculating.

Comment: @MHH - Well, that's not what I wrote, but since you ask, I suppose it depends on the stock. Can Walmart ever go to zero? I doubt it. To be clear, I was making a point, not setting up a thesis. A proper investing mix should have close to zero probability of 'going to zero.'

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer people could have said something similar about General Motors or Kmart a long time ago. Big companies, even as big and profitable as Walmart, can go zero as time goes on. But I agree with your main point that a proper investing mix should have close to zero probability of 'going to zero.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most definitely can invest such an amount profitably, but it makes it even more important to avoid fees, um, *at all costs*, because fees tend to have a fixed component that will be much worse for you than for someone investing €200k. So:

- Get an account at a discount online broker that has no account fees. I don't want to influence you, but I'm using the bank Dirk Nowitzki does endorsements for in Germany, and I'm pretty happy with them.
- Look through their portfolio of index funds and ETFs. Your most important criterium is the Total Expense Ratio (how much of their money they take each year to cover their costs and make a profit). It should be below 0.5%, the lower the better. Ideally, the index which the fund tracks should cover many stocks and different countries (i.e. not the DAX 30), but that tends to come with a higher TER. It would also be great if the fund reinvests dividends (*Thesaurierende Ertragsverwendung* in German).
- Choose a single fund and put all your money in it.
- Ideally do cost averaging in the future: Each month, buy more of the fund for a fixed amount of Euros. Given your small amounts, this requires the bank/broker to support it specfically (*Sparplan*).

**Edit:**
The above assumes that you actually want to *invest* in the long run, for modest but relatively certain gains (maybe 5% above inflation) while accepting temporary downswings of up to 30%. If those €2000 are "funny money" that you don't mind losing but would be really excited about maybe getting 100% return in less than 5 years, well, feel free to put them into an individual stock of an obscure small company, but be aware that you'd be gambling, not investing, and you can probably get better quotes playing Roulette.

Answer (score 1):

I'm of the opinion that speculating is for young people like you, because they can afford to lose it all. Avoiding losses becomes necessary once you have to sustain a family, and manage a somewhat large retirement funds. Even if you lose all your money when speculating, you'll probably be better off later, because you make less costly mistakes once you have larger amounts of money.

1. Go to a broker, don't invest/speculate directly through a bank. Most banks love overcharging clients when buying or selling anything.
2. Most brokers that have very low fees, low enough to turn a profit when buying and selling many times per day, require a minimum deposit of 5-6 digits. That's more than you have, so day trading (open and close a position in a single day) won't work for you.
3. Since you can't change positions often, set yourself timeframes for which you invest. These have to be long enough that the profit doesn't all get lost on the fees. E.g. you buy a stock, or an option, and decide that you will sell in 2 months. Panicking and closing positions too early, is one of the 2 most common mistakes new traders make. The other is getting greedy and closing a position too late.
4. When investing in options (or futures), be aware that options contracts have lot sizes. The quoted price is for an option on 1 stock, but if you buy one you buy 1 contract, which is for 50 or 100 stocks, and costs 50 to 100 times more.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider 'investing' a portion of that money into educating yourself. The payoff might not be as immediately obvious or gratifying but with appropriate determination, in the long term it will generate you a much greater return.

If you would like to learn about investing, a great starting point would be to buy and read the book 'The Intelligent Investor' by Benjamin Graham. This will be a great barometer for how ready you are to invest in the stock market.

If you are able to understand the concepts discussed and comprehend why they are important, you will have gone far in ensuring that you will make adequate returns over your lifetime and will - more importantly - increase the odds of safeguarding your capital.

Answer (score 0):

I have an opposite view from all the other contributions here. Why not consider starting your own business. With the little money you have the return will most times be much higher than stocks return. The business is yours; you keep the business and the profit streams in the long term. Simply find businesses you can even start with a 100 or 200 euros and keep the rest with your bank. this is a sure way to become millionaire my friends.

Comment: Starting a business and turning a profit on it takes a **huge** amount of work, commonly a year or more at way above working "full time", and many fail before then. Also, 10,000x (or even 5,000x) return on investment is frankly completely unrealistic unless you have *zero* capital expenses, and very unrealistic even then. For comparison, not as a business plan, for €200 you might get a printer to print invoices on and *possibly* a second-hand computer to hook it up to, but by then you will be out of money; while some do try their best to, it's hard to turn a profit just by mailing invoices.